# System file contain mount command

Tags: sd-card, mount

I'm searching for file that mount all android partition like system,cache,etc. Why I want to do that? Because I had partitioned my SD to Fat and Ext4 and I want the Ext4 Partition as Internal SD and Fat as External SD (My device doesn't have Internal SD). I'm using Ext4 because when I search in Google "fastest file system" then the result are Ext3 and Ext4.

I have tried to edit vold.fstab but Android 4.0 or just mine doesn't support other filesystem except Fat. Then I have and idea why don't edit file that mount system or cache,etc then make my Ext4 partition as Internal SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the kernel, not just the mount command, that determines what filesystems are supported by your device. To add support for filesystems your device doesn't already, you need to find the kernel sources and config for your device, reconfigure the kernel to enable the filesystem you want, build a new boot.img, and flash it to your device.

Since that's essentially how to port and build a custom ROM, the exact details of how to do this are well beyond the scope of this site. You might be able to find a custom ROM for your device that already supports the filesystem you want: see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) for more information on how to find custom ROMs.

BTW, it seems quite unlikely that your device only supports FAT. Since Android is Linux-based, it's more usual to use a filesystem like ext3 for the internal filesystems, and only FAT for the SD card. But since you didn't tell us what device you have, I can't say for sure.

Comment: My device support Ext4 or Ext3 because I already use that for Internal Memory (/data/) but I can't use it for Internal SD. so you say kernel? I had read in a blog that init.rc file in kernel used for mount partition, thx for your help

Comment: Thx for the clue, I will search throught my kernel then